# Select Option from Element | Cucumber Testing Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

We are having trouble getting cucumber to check our drop-down menu for a web app we are building in class. Currently, our all(selector).last is giving us nill. Can someone provide a direction for us to look at fixing this?

ERROR:

```
 When I select option "Group A" from element "prog_user_role_id"          # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:91
      undefined method `find' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
      ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:92:in `/^I select option "(.*?)" from element "(.*?)"$/'
      features/support/prog_user.feature:19:in `I select option "Group A" from element "prog_user_role_id"'
```

web_steps.rb -- I've tried a few different ones as you can see from comments. Would love any direction or insight.

```
When(/^I select option "(.*?)" from "(.*?)"$/) do |option, selector|
  all(selector).last.find(:option, option).select_option
    
  #select('option', from: 'prog_user_role_id')
  #select("Group A", from: "prog_user_role_id").select_option
end
```

[HTML from inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4crNG.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please post all code as text and not images.

Comment: Thanks. I've fixed. I left the html snip as a picture because it is just easier.